# How to query from Apollo cache not having the query on ROOT_QUERY

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need to implement a list of nested items (tasks), every task should be editable, like this

[image]

I've got two variants of how to do it with React/Apollo/GraphQL:

**1. useQuery for every task separately**

This works well but lots of queries for every task separately

**2. 2 queries: 1 to fetch all tasks from the server, 1 to get one from the CACHE**

My idea is that somewhere in the parent component I'd fetch all available tasks, like this:

```
const TASKS_NESTED = gql`
    query TaskWithNestedChildren($taskId: String!) {
        taskWithNestedChildren(taskId: $taskId) {
            _id
            name
            children {
                _id
            }
        }
    }
`;

const ParentComp = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery(TASKS_NESTED, {
        variables: { taskId: parentTaskId },
    });
```

This would write all tasks into the cache

And in my child component I'd get task's data from the cache, like this

```
const TASK = gql`
    query Task($taskId: String!) {
        task(taskId: $taskId) {
            _id
            name
            children {
                _id
            }
        }
    }
`;

const Task = ({...}) => {

    const { data, loading } = useQuery(TASK, {
        variables: { taskId },
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-only',
    });
```

it doesn't load every Task from the Cache, it says:

> Can't find field 'task' on ROOT_QUERY object

[image]

here's my schema on Node.js side

```
type Query {
    task(taskId: String!): Task
    taskWithNestedChildren(taskId: String!): [Task]
}
```

which means the `taskWithNestedChildren` returns array of tasks-Objects and `task` returns one Task object

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION 1**
In child component get task data from the cache using `client.readFragment`.

```
const task = client.readFragment({
    id: `Task:${taskId}`,
    fragment: TASK_FRAGMENT,
});
```

The problem with this approach is that Task (Child) component is not subscribed to any cache changes, and when the cache is updated the Component is not rerendered.

Any other solutions?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/local-resolvers/#querying-local-state

Comment: that's something completely different and deprecated @xadm

Comment: Hi, does "children" in "Task" type refers to "taskWithNestedChildren" ? If yes, you may try this : https://hashinteractive.com/blog/graphql-recursive-query-with-fragments/

If you still can't figure it out, please make it reproductible with https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo-error-template or https://codesandbox.io/s/github/apollographql/react-apollo-error-template and I'd be happy to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

1- use **@client** as following in the query so that it uses the cache

```
const TASK = gql`
    query Task($taskId: String!) {
        task(taskId: $taskId)@client {
            _id
            name
            children {
                _id
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

2- also add **typePolicies** so that it defines the logic of querying task since it's not in the root query

read more about that here
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/